# how to set outbound_interface with ipv6 address?

Tags: boost-asio

I'm developing a multicast receiver. How to setup `boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface` for socket if my interface has ipv6 address?
According examples it should be ipv4: `_socket.set_option( boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface(if_addr.to_v4()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not good documentation for asio. I've found required information in sources:

`_socket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface(ipv6addr.scope_id()));`